# FOURIER SERIES trigonometric functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

What will the Fourier series of function $\sin 2x$ between the limits $-\pi<x<\pi$ be?

Comment: Did you attempt solving it? Have you got any steps that you could show us? Looking at the definition of Fourier series will help you. Please don't expect people doing your homework for you here.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function $\phi (x)\in L^2(a,b)$, then you can rewrite it in terms of basis functions of Fourier space. The basis functions are $sin(nx)$ and $cos(nx)$. Now you have, $sin(2x)$, that is already one of basis of Fourier series. So you have the solution!